# In a kv file, how do I transfer methods from a parent to its children

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I have created a custom widget (parent) with a switch among its children.
I would like to set a method in the parent to be called by the switch on the on_active event.

The goal is that every time I create a new iteration of my custom widget, I can easily set the method for the child switch. My current attempt doesn't generate any error, but when I activate the switch, nothing happens.

What's the correct way to achieve this process?

Thanks

```
<MyParentWidget@Widget>:
    title: ""
    action: []
    Label:
        text: root.title
        ...
    Switch:
        on_active: root.action
        ...

<CustomDropDown>:
    ...
    MyParentWidget:
        title: 'my option 1'
        action: app.myMethod1()
    MyParentWidget:
        title: 'my option 2'
        action: app.myMethod2()
```

Comment: I looked at Kivy's [Switch](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.switch.html) widget and I haven't seen `on_active` property.

Comment: I was using on_touch_up at the beginning. but when I was doing tests by directly bonding a method to this event, it was systematically called 3 times in a row. After looking on forums, it was proposed to use on_active instead, and the method is then correctly called. strange behaviour, I agree.

Comment: It's not strange at all... Every kivy property (e.g. `active`) produces an event when changed. You can have access to that event by the `on_`+`event_name` scheme. Its not even unique :o) PyQt/Pyside does it too (and perhaps also other frameworks). As for your question, the second approach should work OK.

Comment: @embryo: Thanks, I learned something new the `on_`+`event_name` scheme (I'm a beginner with Python and Kivy) ;) Any idea to solve my method calling issue? Thanks!

Comment: As I said, I think that the second approach should work. Other than that you have to post a [mcve], so I can be more specific...

Comment: @embryo: I'ms sorry, I don't see which second approach you're talking about (I'm probably a bit tired). Could you please be more explicit? Concerning the code, I simply removed the elements such as positions, size, etc and the python code, as I consider it doesn't help to focus on the issue and shouldn't be necessary. But if you want me to add more specific code, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: One way you could do it is to have your switches all call the same function and pass some identifier of the widget calling the function, e.g. `on_active: app.my_method(root.title)`. Then you could have your `my_method` function call the correct function afterwards, like `if title == 'my option 1': myMethod1()`. Kind of roundabout but it should work

Comment: This is what happens if there is no explicit, runnable code. I interpreter your 2 widgets as 2 approaches to run a command from a kv widget action. That's why I was saying that the `action: app.myMethod1()/app.myMethod2()` approach should work. Or better yet as @gpreux wrote, use just one and pass it an id or the widget itself...